# What is the result of persuading Leliana to kill or not kill a traitor agent?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Some point fairly early on in Haven you can approach Leliana while she is ordering an assassination of an old friend of hers, someone who is a traitor to the inquisition.  You can enforce the death order, persuade otherwise or remain silent.  What are the long term effects in each case?

Comment: This question could be asked for so many branches on so many quests in DAI. Is there a reason you are interested in this specific part of the game (perhaps we can put some other concerns to rest)? It might be covered in an official players guide. I seem to recall the DA2 official guide described the results/consequences of most decisions. No idea what the DAI guide looks like though (in fact I'm gonna go look for a copy to download right now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't terribly direct consequences to this conversation with Leliana, nor does she have an approval rating like the combat followers. However, towards the end of the game

> You get to help influence the choice of the new Divine, and Leliana is one of the candidates. If she does end up elected to the position, your choices while interacting with her will influence how the epilogue describes her reign. She may become a caring Divine who urges for unity, or a vicious and deadly Divine, described as having blood run through the halls of the Grand Cathedral.